# How to relate to users answering "too much"

Tags: discussion

This might seem as a recursive matter; also I'm mostly relating to the IT sites of SO, but this might involve other sites too.

I'm a musician and a teacher and, in my experience, answering to questions is a very good way to learn things.
I'm not a professional programmer, but I enjoy coding; in the last years I think that I've got some experience that can be helpful for others, and, in the same way, it can be useful for me too. Going back to the recursive reference, my acquiring of experience can be useful to other people too, and so on.

Answering on StackOverflow <s>is not</s> should not be a race, and I really am not interested in ratings (as a famous musician already pointed out, «Competitions are for horses, not for artists», and I think that coding can be some form of art). But.

I noticed that there are some skillful users that seem to spend most of their time answering questions in SO, usually in the matter of minutes.

While from the "basic" point of view this is actually helpful for the current OP, I have to admit that, from an "external" learning point of view, this can be sometimes annoying, as it is not as "engaging" as it could: I see the answer, I concur with it, let's move on.

I'm following some traditional mailing lists that have much slower response time, and I realized that I've actually (actively) learnt more from the answers I gave there than from here.

Don't get me wrong. I really am grateful to those users, as they usually offer useful answers (even if, sometimes, they are too much succinct), but I really have the feeling that that amount of quick-answers might not be a real advantage in the "whole picture" meaning of learning that SO might point to.
As said, I'm not a programmer, and I've not that much time to dedicate to SO, but I think that there's plenty of professionals (and "normal" people) who could even improve their skills as much as me, if there was more possibility and engagement to do so: if you see an interesting question with a given answer, it's "learning level" is not as high as answering it by yourself.

As a teacher, always willing to learn, I usually try to let my students give their own answers first, expecially from group lessons, as I think it's a meaningful way to learn new things and new way to look at things, for them and for myself.

So, my question is actually a meta-mix of questions (we're on meta, right? ;-) ).
How do we relate to those users?
Is the purpose of SO to just give answers to people asking them? Those people reply in a correct (and usually insightful) way, but this just creates finite answers, not compelling ones.
Shouldn't be here room for other people answering, and with "room" I also mean "time to answer"?

Comment: There is plenty of room for more than one answer to a question.  Generally not what the questioner needs or wants, but he's only one and there will be many more visitors.  Just do it the way you want to do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Technically I'd agree with you. But when the (correct) answer has been already given, adding another similar answer won't be the same, and would just add some useless background noise. What I mean is that, yes, I know that SO is a Q&A site, but simple Q&As alone never have gotten people that far. I've always thought as SO (an the Internet in general) as a place to share information in a way that it would bring people to think, not just find answers they were looking for. And that's from both points of view, people asking and those answering them or even asking new ones themselves.

Comment: High quality answers are more than just code dumps, and therefore take time to write. What you describe is known as the Fastest Gun in the West problem, and has existed since the earliest days of Stack Overflow. Just ignore it. Answer the questions you find interesting as best as you possibly can. You can't effectively slow down the fastest guns, but you can provide better content than they can, content that stands the test of time and helps more people than the original asker. No Q&A here is ever really "complete". If you have something more to add, post it.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. With my limited English knowledge I wasn't able to dig deeper and find answers about this topic (the "Fastest Gun" problem has cleared things up a lot). It's just that whenever I see an answer that pratically answers to the question asked I don't always feel like adding something else is interesting and useful as it could - I even feel like I'm almost trying to "prove I'm better" just trying to do so: I know I'm giving my contribution anyway, but being able to give my own complete answer is kind of different. Btw, I'll try and keep all this in mind the next time this happens.

Comment: @musicamante it sounds like your proposal is "make people who *know correct answer* wait till people who *have wrong answers* have chance to post some random content"... (Note that SO is not a classroom - "I usually try to let my students give their own answers first" can't be motivation here)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not at all, and I know this is not a classroom (luckily!). I don't have an actual proposal, but maybe showing some sort of alert to "Fastest gun" users, almost as it could happen in a classroom when you've a talented pupil that _always_ answers; something like "Hey, you already answered 100 questions this week in a matter of minutes, why don't you give other people some time to do so?": not a limitation, just a suggestion. I know it could potentially damage users waiting for an answer ASAP, but I think that in the long run it could be an improvement from a larger point of view.

Comment: Well. Here I am, some 4 years later. My supposed "humbleness" and "I have rights to take my time to answer!" was *mostly* common inexperience (Dunning, Kruger, are you there?). Being a teacher teaches you nothing until it does. I turned out to be one of those supposedly "fastest guns", and the pandemic probably ("luckily"?!? :-/ ) helped in improving my "performance": users I initially watched in suspect when giving those "fast answers" have actually become a reference for reliability, knowledge and experience. Damn, sometimes I ask myself if I should *wait* before providing an answer.

Comment: Yet, I feel compelled to answer, given my acquired experience. I know I can still fail after all this time, but I also I know I can provide (possibly) valid, useful, insightful answers that can help people. Not "as fast as I can", but "as soon as I see something that might *really* help anybody" (including myself). Yeah, the "system" isn't perfect, the gamification can result in derailing behavior (again, including myself!), but the purpose remains: helping. So, to any "future me" that may feel a similar case: don't give up, don't care too much for the wrong reasons. Just "do it!" [cit.].

Answer (score 6):

> How do we relate to those users?

Make an effort to empathize. They have competency and are willing to help others, and deserve whatever recognition the system gives them for doing so.

> Is the purpose of SO to just give answers to people asking them?

No, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a library of canonical questions and answers. People getting quick answers to their questions is a great and expected side-effect, but that's not the main purpose of the site.

> Those people reply in a correct (and usually insightful) way, but this just creates finite answers, not compelling ones.

Then these questions are unlikely to be canonical questions - so write compelling answers on canonical questions where people will actually read them in the long run.

> Shouldn't be here room for other people answering, and with "room" I also mean "time to answer"?

If by "time to answer" you mean you want some kind of delay before answers popped up, then that would hurt the askers who are waiting for an answer, wouldn't it?

This is gamified ranked Q&A. You are trying to participate, and I appreciate that you want to do so, but you are participating on a level playing field with users that include highly competent subject matter experts.

Perhaps you can write a more inspired answer than they can - but they can write a quick and correct answer faster than you can.

I faced this same problem.

So I focus on writing comprehensive answers to canonical questions. This activity has eventually resulted in recognition and greatly improved my own competency in the subject matter.

I could likely compete much better answering new questions - but at this point, I really don't have the time for competitive answering.

Comment: As per my citation, I don't like _that_ kind of competition, and I don't have time to dedicate to it. I thought about time delayed answers and I agree with you that it would hurt the OPs. I know that there's no such thing as perfect ranking, and sometimes it can be annoying as people commenting "First!". I'll try and make peace with it; who knows, maybe once I'll get past ignoring this kind of things, I'll also be able to peacefully answer in my own way, even if another answer has already been given, finding it as compelling as giving a brand new answer. Thanks.